# How to rise touchesBegan event in UIWebBrowser in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiviewcontroller

```
@interface MyBrowser: UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
           IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

I have a class and a UIWebView in it i want to use the - **touchesBegan** event when i touch to my web browser ... But I can't because that event didn't rise ... Who know why that event didn't rise and what i must do to get it !!!

Comment: Try by setting `self.webView.delegate = self` in .m file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol TapDetectingWindowDelegate
- (void)userDidTapWebView:(id)tapPoint; @end

@interface TapDetectingWindow : UIWindow {
    UIView *viewToObserve;
    id <TapDetectingWindowDelegate> controllerThatObserves; } @property (nonatomic, retain) UIView
*viewToObserve; @property (nonatomic, assign) id <TapDetectingWindowDelegate> controllerThatObserves;

@end

#import "TapDetectingWindow.h"
@implementation TapDetectingWindow
@synthesize viewToObserve;
@synthesize controllerThatObserves;
- (id)initWithViewToObserver:(UIView *)view andDelegate:(id)delegate {
    if(self == [super init]) {
        self.viewToObserve = view;
        self.controllerThatObserves = delegate;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [viewToObserve release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)forwardTap:(id)touch {
    [controllerThatObserves userDidTapWebView:touch];
}
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];
    if (viewToObserve == nil || controllerThatObserves == nil)
        return;
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    if (touches.count != 1)
        return;
    UITouch *touch = touches.anyObject;
    if (touch.phase != UITouchPhaseEnded)
        return;
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:viewToObserve] == NO)
        return;
    CGPoint tapPoint = [touch locationInView:viewToObserve];
    NSLog(@"TapPoint = %f, %f", tapPoint.x, tapPoint.y);
    NSArray *pointArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", tapPoint.x],
                           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", tapPoint.y], nil];
    if (touch.tapCount == 1) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(forwardTap:) withObject:pointArray afterDelay:0.5];
    }
    else if (touch.tapCount > 1) {
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(forwardTap:) object:pointArray];
    }
}
@end
```

I add this code to my application when I add this code:

```
@interface MiniBrowser : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, TapDetectingWindow>{  IBOutlet UIWebView *webView; }

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

But when I want to run my application annot find protocol declaration for TapDetectingWindow error appears !!! What does it mean ??? What I must to do ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best post i found for that-

http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way

Comment: I try to do like in the example but when I want to run application cannot find protocol declaration for TapDetectingWindow error appears !!!